# Selecting only sheets matching name

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a macro which will run through the files in the folder and then copy sheets from all excel files to the workbook from which the macro was run.

This part works as charm, what I want to do is to select and copy sheets that match exact name.

```
For Each wksCurSheet In wbkSrcBook.Sheets
  'I reckon I should add some if statement in here
  countSheets = countSheets + 1
  wksCurSheet.Copy after:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)
Next
```

Honestly, I have no idea how to write that statement, examples I found were quite confusing and when I try something by myself, I get weird errors.

```
If (wksCurSheet.Name == "AO-SC") Then
If (wksCurSheet.Name as String == "AO-SC") Then
If (wksCurSheet.("AO-SC")) Then
```

What's the correct way?

Comment: The comparison operator in VBA is a single equals sign, not double.

Comment: "I get weird errors" isn't really helpful. Insert an actual error message you get.

Comment: Weird errors = line is red, no idea why

Comment: A red line means syntax error. Means: What you typed in that line is no valid VBA code.

Comment: I didn't expect that assign and comparison operators are both single equals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way to get the specific worksheet through loop:

```
For Each wksCurSheet In wbkSrcBook.Worksheets
  If wksCurSheet.Name = "AO-SC" Then
      'Do something
  End If
Next
```

This is how to use it with two worksheets:

```
If wksCurSheet.Name = "AO-SC" Or wksCurSheet.Name = "SomethingElse" Then
```

And if the worksheets, you are interestd in are saved in an array, you can use a custom function `valueInArray`, checking whether the worksheet's name is part of the predefined array:

```
Public Function valueInArray(myValue As Variant, myArray As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim cnt As Long
    For cnt = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        If CStr(myValue) = CStr(myArray(cnt)) Then
            valueInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next cnt
End Function
```

This is how to use it:

```
predefinedArrayWithNames = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2","Sheet3")
If valueInArray(wksCurSheet.Name, predefinedArrayWithNames) Then
```

Comment: Your function could be a one-liner using match.

Comment: @SJR - can you come up with an example of a one-liner with `Match`?

Comment: `valueInArray = IsNumeric(Application.Match(myValue, myArray, 0))`

Comment: @SJR - 1 liner indeed, but these are two functions. Furthermore, the custom function forces comparison of Strings, thus with `Match` this `IsNumeric(Application.Match(10, Array("10"), 0))` would be false.

Comment: @SJR - Thanks. Actually one of the "retired" functions I was using `b_value_in_array` was actually using `Application.Match` at the end with `IsError` instead of `IsNumeric` - https://github.com/Vitosh/VBA_personal/blob/master/__Arch/00.vb